Simulating a battery in a portable audio amplifier
I have a Topping G5 portable battery-powered audio D/A converter and amplifier. This device has two USB ports: one solely for digital audio input and the other for charging.

I've always used the device plugged in, but over time, this caused the battery to swell due to overcharging. After removing the swollen battery, I discovered that the device won't operate with just the charging USB port connected—it requires a battery to be installed.
I would like to know if there's a way to simulate the presence of a battery in this device since I would likely soon be dealing with another swollen battery after prolonged overcharging.
Inside the device, the charging USB port is directly connected to a circuit that interfaces with a 2-pin 1.5mm JST connector for the 805080 Li-Po battery. I can't modify the connection between the USB port and the JST connector - I need a solution that connects to the JST. There's plenty of space inside the device where the battery used to be.
Is there a way to simulate a battery in this scenario? If so, how?
Would there be a way to use the preexisting USB Charge port for power?
Detail of the Charge USB on the inside:

Overview of the internals with the battery removed, arrowing pointing at the JST connector for the battery:


Could you provide a part number for the battery? Is the JST connector 2 pin, 3 pin or more? (Some batteries come with temperature sense line.)

@MathKeepsMeBusy it was a generic 805080 battery - LiPo 3.7V 4000 mAh. the JST is 2-pin 1.5mm

(a) Is the Power Indicator "Steady red" when you tried to use the device with no battery fitted and the charge USB port connected (b) Is it possible to get a picture of the other side of the PCB? If we can identify which device is used to charger / monitor the battery, that could help how to determine how to simulate the battery.

@ChesterGillon When I try turning it on plugged in, without a battery, the power indicator starts blinking (behavior unseen with a battery) and there is a repeating clicking sound (relay? not sure). Unfortunately I don't think I can take the PCB out and take a picture of the other side without damaging the case and I couldnt find a photo online
